# Removing default constructor used by YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, serialization, default-constructor, yamldotnet

I have an object graph containing nodes of various types. All nodes derive from a Node class. Using YamlDotNet I've managed to serialize and deserialize the graph by providing my own implementation of `IObjectFactory`. The only thing left to do is to get rid of a constructor that only exists to please the YamlDotNet serializer.

Have a look at the following .NET fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/KJMzxD

The `FancyNode.ctor()` is the constructor I would like to remove but I'm not sure how to tell the serializer that I've handled everything in the deserializer. If I simply remove it I get the following error

> Type 'FancyNode' cannot be deserialized because it does not have a default constructor or a type converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get rid of the parameterless constructor code rather than the constructor itself - given it's required for that type of deserialisation - you could remove both constructors and use a factory method to create the nodes. That would result in the class having a default public constructor.

For example, change:

> ```
> public class FancyNode : Node
> {
>   private IController controller;
>
>   public string ID
>   {
>       get;
>       private set;
>   }
>
>   // I would really like to get rid of this constructor
>   public FancyNode()
>   {
>       throw new NotSupportedException();
>   }
>
>   // NOTICE: no default constructor here  
>   public FancyNode(IController controller, string id)
>   {
>       this.controller = controller;
>       this.ID = id;
>   }
> }
> ```

to:

```
public class FancyNode : Node
{
    private IController controller;

    public string ID
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static FancyNode CreateNode(IController controller, string id)
    {
        var node = new FancyNode();
        node.controller = controller;
        node.ID = id;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Yes you lose the tight control you have that doesn't allow the object to be created without passing those parameters in, given that anyone can now do `var x = new FancyNode()`. Then again you aren't validating the parameters so it makes no difference to calling it with `new FancyNode(null, null)`.

Comment: Good thinking, however I would not just like to remove the constructor from code, I don't want the default constructor at all. I want YamlDotNet to fail when not configured properly and not just default to a default constructor thinking it will suffice.